# Is there a noop iterator in the stl?

Tags: c++, stl

If I wanted to copy the same value across an iterator range, I would think that it would be easy to have a noop iterator where you pass it a value, and when it is incremented, it would not move anywhere.  This would allow using the existing `std::copy` and `std::copy_if` algorithms.

However, I can't seem to find such a beast.  Am I going to have to roll my own?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question here, but `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` might be more suitable for such a task?

Comment: If it does not move anywhere how would it stop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or `std::fill_n` algorithm.

Some containers, e.g. `std::vector<>` and `std::list<>`, have a constructor with size and initializer:

```
std::vector<int> v(10, 42); // 42 is the initializer
v.resize(20, 42); // Initialize new elements with 42.
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that.  Need some caffeine. ;)

Comment: Featuring: one of the most dangerous constructors in the standard library :)

Comment: @lubgr, how so?

Comment: If you change `v(10, 42)` to `v{10, 42}` you end up with a vector of size 2 and elements 10 and 42.

Comment: @lubgr The constructor was absolutely fine – until uniform initialisation appeared...

Comment: `std::initializer_list`, the most dangerous type to feature in a constructor, especially when retrofitted into an existing container

Comment: Oh @lubgr, I thought you were talking about `std::fill`.

Comment: @lubgr Just to generalize your logic: any function taking more than one argument of the same type next to each other is dangerous. Right?

Comment: @KABoissonneault It is not `std::initializer_list` either, it is uniform initialisation, at least in the form it was introduced – if `v{{10, 42}}` had been made mandatory, no problem at all... Still I consider `v({10, 42})` (classic initialisation combined with initialiser list) *much* more readable.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no iterator for this but there is an algorithm.  [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) will take a range an assign a value to each element that is returned from the generator passed to it.  If you want to assign everything 42 for instance that would look like

```
std::vector<int> vec(20);
std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), []() { return 42; });
```

You can even get values that change like

```
std::vector<int> vec(20);
std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), []() { static int counter = 0; ++counter; return counter * counter; });
```

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, no.  Not when you have `std::fill`.